# Sync My Calendar with Outlook/Exchange 2010 using Kies messes up dates on Galaxy S II

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, calendar, samsung-kies, outlook

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II running Gingerbread (2.3.5). I tried synchronizing My Calendar with Outlook/Exchange 2010 (Outlook running on Win7) using Kies (over USB).

I started with a clean calendar on the phone and the Kies indeed transferred all the appointments and events to the phone, however there is a problem interpreting the dates. Any appointment taking place on a day of the month up to the 12th - the day of the month is interpreted as the month itself, and the month is interpreted as the day. Thus - March 9 becomes September 3, etc. Oddly enough, March 15 stays March 15.

Any ideas what configuration needs to be corrected, and where?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, sounds like a localization issue, perhaps. Out of curiosity, what country do you live in, and what language do you have your SGSII set for? Could be a disconnect of some sort between the locale Kies is expecting and the locale of your phone.

Comment: Agree with Eldarerathis it sounds exactly like you've got one device set to US date format, and the other set to normal date format. Either the PC or the phone is running with the wrong regional settings, and Kies isn't clever enough to convert as it syncs.

Comment: Side note: sync via ActiveSync over the air is much better than USB--if your server supports it. Highly recommended over the Kies method.

Comment: Sorry for the late response to your help...
Thanks for the suggestions. I checked the date format already and both are using normal date format. Any secret places on the phone that this setting could be messed up? I checked in the general phone date settings - couldn't find any calendar specific settings.

Sadly, our corporation does not allow ActiveSync with our exchange server...

Comment: I might try setting the phone to US format and see what happens :-)

Comment: Ended up switching from Kies to MyPhoneExplorer. Sorry Samsung...